# Android doesn't finding JSONValue class

Tags: java, android, maven, jar

I'm very new to android and I get this error when I try to run my android project.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.JSONValue
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at in.juspay.PaymentService.initOrder(PaymentService.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at com.example.HelloMobile.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  502):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have jar file which is written by me and built using maven tool. When I do :

```
mvn clean install
```

there where no error and everything works file but when I add the jar to my android project and try to run I'm getting this error.

Here are my maven dependencies from `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Not sure why the error occurs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar you got after "mvn clean install" only contains the class from your project. Classes from those dependency jar are not included, so you got a NoClassDefFoundError exception.

If you really need to build a fat jar, which include all the dependencies, I will suggest maven-assembly-plugin. Following is a working example(put it in your pom.xml):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <!-- This will bind assembly:make-assembly to the package phase -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After you get the jar(in target directory), you can run "jar -tf theJarFile" to check whether the class is included.

Comment: How do I install `maven-assembly-plugin`?

Comment: Thanks. After updating the `pom.xml` file. I can just run `mvn clean install`?

Comment: I'm getting an error like this : `'single' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin`

Comment: Run "mvn help:effective-pom" and check the version of maven-assembly-plugin. You may have a wrong version.